# Chef-zero error when creating a docker container from OSX

Tags: macos, docker, chef-infra

I'm trying to create a docker container from OSX using the latest docker for OSX.  chef-zero is able to build the basic container, but then can't find the chef-zero server running because it is looking on the wrong IP address.  It's using the docker0 IP address instead of the address of my mac host.  I can't seem to override it, even with the chef_server attribute.   It uses that server IP when creating the container, but not from within the container.  How do I get this to work.  When I try to override the server, I get a bad URI error.  There are no examples of the format of the chef_server property.

```
  Error executing action `converge` on resource 'machine[wario]'
================================================================================

URI::InvalidURIError
--------------------
bad URI(is not URI?): 

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /Users/stevelowenthal/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/docker/recipes/sample2.rb

  3: machine 'wario' do
  4: #    recipe 'openssh::default'
  5:     recipe 'workstation_tools::install_java8'
  6:     
  7:     chef_server :url => "http://10.201.20.20:8889"
```